# Solving $\cos(3x) = \cos(2x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, cubics

I'm struggling with solving given trigonometric equation

$$\cos(3x) = \cos(2x)$$

Let's take a look at the trigonometric identities we can use:

$$\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2-1$$

and

$$\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3(x) -3\cos(x)$$

Plugging into the equation and we have that

$$4\cos^3(x) -3\cos(x) = 2\cos^2(x)-1$$

$$4\cos^3(x) -3\cos(x) - 2\cos^2(x)+1= 0$$

Recalling $t = \cos (x)$,

$$4t^3-2t^2-3t +1 = 0$$

Which is a cubic equation. Your sincerely helps will be appreciated.

Regards!

Comment: With questions like this, I wouldn't usually answer when several others already have, but sometimes I post an answer because I think the others are more complicated than they could be.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Give different answer to any OP is always a good and very useful habit. For the "more complicated" issue I think that it is mainly a subjective matter. For example by your answer we need to consider polynomilas, factorization, quadratic equations but the solution can be obtained directly by the definition of trigonometric functions by a simple first order equation. What is simpler?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By the definition of cosine function we have that

$$\cos \alpha = \cos \theta \iff \alpha = \theta +2k\pi \, \lor \, \alpha = -\theta +2k\pi \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

[image]

and thus

$$\cos(3x) = \cos(2x)\iff 3x=2x+2k\pi \, \lor \, 3x=-2x+2k\pi  \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

that is

- $x=2k\pi$
- $x=\frac25 k\pi$

Comment: What does that $2k\pi$ mean? How? I still didn't get it.

Comment: No, that's now what I meant.

Comment: @Hamilton $2k\pi$ is a integer multiple of $2\pi$

Comment: Why did you use that method? Can I use it for other trigonometric equations too?

Comment: @Hamilton That's the more effective way to solve this kind of equations. The first line is the key point.

Comment: @Hamilton: Isn't it a good reason to use the method that it happens to work? You can use it for other equations where it works -- though as applied here it is somewhat restricted in that it only works well when you need to equate two raw sines or cosines, with no coefficients or constant terms.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've just researched whether there are identities as gimusi mentioned. However, I couldn't find anything useful. Honestly, I've never seen a identitiy like this one $\cos \alpha = \cos \theta \iff \alpha = \theta +2k\pi \quad \lor \quad  \alpha = -\theta +2k\pi \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}$ Hence it made me confused.

Comment: @Hamilton It is a trivial identity from the definition of $\cos x$ indeed by periodicity $\cos x=\cos (x+2k\pi)$ and since $\cos x$ is even $\cos x=\cos (-x+2k\pi)$. You can also see the identity by the trigonometric circle.

Comment: @gimusi Any books that you recommend me to read concerning trigonometric equations?

Comment: @Hamilton I do not have to suggest any particular book, just refer to any good source and try to understand the basic definition for trigonometric functions and how to derive the main identities.  A good reference for a summary is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities. For example how would you solve $\sin (3x)= \sin (2x)$ according to the basic definitions?

Answer (score 8):

The equality $\cos(3x)=\cos(2x)$ is obviously true when $x=0$ and thus when $t=1.$ Therefore the polynomial
$$
4t^3-2t^2-3t +1
$$
has $t=1$ as one of its zeros. Consequently it can be factored:
$$
4t^3-2t^2-3t +1 = (t-1)(\cdots\cdots\cdots)
$$
The other zeros are those of a quadratic polynomial, written here as $(\cdots\cdots\cdots).$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

You can use sum-product equivalence. Which is:

$$\cos(A)-\cos(B)=-2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$$
so,

$$\cos(3x)-\cos(2x)=0\to-2\sin\left(\frac{3x+2x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{3x-2x}{2}\right)=0$$

$$\sin\left(\frac{5x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=0$$
so,

$$\sin\left(\frac{5x}{2}\right)=0 \text{ or } \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Calling

$$
\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}
$$

we have

$$
e^{3ix}+e^{-3i x} = e^{2ix}+e^{-2i x} 
$$

or calling $z = e^{ix}$

$$
z^6+1 = z^5+z\to z^6-z^5-z+1 = (z-1)^2(z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1) = (z^5-1)(z-1) = 0
$$

so the solutions are obvious.

$$
x = \frac{2\pi}{5}k,\;\; \mbox{for}\;\; k=0,1,2,\cdots
$$

Answer (score 3):

To complement gimusi's fine answer, there are other cases when simple methods work:

1. $\cos f(x)=\cos g(x)$
2. $\sin f(x)=\sin g(x)$
3. $\tan f(x)=\tan g(x)$
4. $\sin f(x)=\cos g(x)$
5. $\cot f(x)=\tan g(x)$

where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are expressions involving the unknown $x$.

Equation 1 has the solutions
$$
f(x)=g(x)+2k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
f(x)=-g(x)+2k\pi
$$

Equation 2 has the solutions
$$
f(x)=g(x)+2k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
f(x)=\pi-g(x)+2k\pi
$$

Equation 3 has the solutions
$$
f(x)=g(x)+k\pi
$$
(of course one has also to exclude values of $x$ that make $\tan f(x)$ or $\tan g(x)$ undefined).

Two angles have the same cosine if and only if the points on the unit circle they correspond to have the same $x$-coordinate; two angles have the same sine if and only if the points on the unit circle have the same $y$-coordinate. The $2k\pi$ or $k\pi$ term, with $k$ an integer, represents the periodicity.

What about an equation of the form $\sin f(x)=\cos g(x)$? We can recall that $\sin\alpha=\cos(\pi/2-\alpha)$, so we can reduce it to
$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-f(x)\right)=\cos g(x)
$$
which is type 1 above.

Similarly, $\cot f(x)=\tan g(x)$ can become
$$
\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-f(x)\right)=\tan g(x)
$$
that is, type 3 above.

Comment: Thanks for the quote! Very nice generalization.