# If $\cos(x+a)=\cos(x+y+z)$, then can we deduce that $a=y+z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If I have the following equation:

$$\cos(x+a)=\cos(x+y+z)$$

Can I take the inverse cos of both sides?

$$\begin{align}
\cos^{-1}(\cos(x + a))&=\cos^{-1}(\cos(x+y+z)) \\
x+a&=x+y+z \\
a&=y+z
\end{align}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: No, you can hardly ever take inverse cosine of both sides, and there appears to be no reason for this to be one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it'is wrong, let instead consider the trigonometric circle to derive that

$$\cos \theta = \cos \alpha \implies \theta = \alpha+2k\pi \quad \lor \quad \theta = -\alpha+2k\pi$$

Refer also to the related

- [Solving $\cos(3x) = \cos(2x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2826222/505767)

Comment: Or if you want a more elementary version of what gimusi is saying, OP - in case you're not familiar with the logic notation and such - it's because:

$$\cos(x) = \cos(x + 2\pi) = \cos(x + 4\pi) = ... = \cos(x + 2k\pi)$$

for any integer $k$. That is to say, it's because the cosine function is periodic, with period $2\pi$. We also have this because cosine is an even function, i.e.

$$\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer That's not complete we also have $$\cos(x) = \cos(-x + 2\pi) = \cos(-x + 4\pi) = ... = \cos(-x + 2k\pi)$$

Comment: I suggest simply to draw the trigonometric circle to check that. it is always the best way to see those simple equalities or inequalities.

Comment: The answer is $a=y+x$. I tried converting to exponential functions and taking the natural logarithm of both sides but I just get zero.

Comment: Yeah, my bad gimusi, I forgot to add in that bit. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Perfect that's fine now but I also suggest to consider the interpretation directly on the trigonometric circle.

Comment: I think I do get it. $a$ has to be equal to $y+z$ no matter what right? Picturing it on the circle helps. If $a$ was $2\pi$ then that just means $cos(x+a) = cos(x)$. Since it is just one complete rotation. Also meaning that $y+z$ has to equal $2\pi$ to satisfy the equation.

Comment: @user367640 That's one (set of) solutions. Can you find the other one?

Comment: infinite more values, correct? If $cos(x)$ experiences a phase shift, $a$ then no matter what that phase shift is, $y+z$ is equal to it.

Comment: @user367640 Yes a set of solution is $a=y+z+2k\pi \quad \forall k\in \mathbb{Z}$. But what about the second case?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that due to $\cos\theta$ having a period of $2\pi$, for any $\lambda, \mu\in\Bbb Z, \theta\in \Bbb R$, we have:

$$\cos(\theta+2\lambda\pi)=\cos(\theta+2\mu\pi)$$

$\lambda=\mu$ is not a necessity to this end.

Effectively in your expression we have that $a=y+z+2\lambda\pi, \lambda \in \Bbb Z$.

$\lambda=0$ is a possibility, and there $a=y+z$, but there are infinitely many other possibilities as well.

Comment: [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xa26zbybdj) is a graph showing why this is the case. $f(x)=\cos^{-1}(x)$ is a *one-to-many* function.