# Find k that satisfies $\cos{(\omega fx)}=\cos{(\omega k x)}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, signal-processing

For which frequency k>f is

$\cos (\omega fx_1)= \cos (\omega kx_1)$

only at point $x_1$.

Like k = 9

$\cos (\omega*1*0.1)= \cos (\omega * 9 * 0.1) \approx 0.809$

I need at general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general we have that:

$$\cos (A)= \cos (B) \iff  A=B+2n\pi \;\lor \; A=-B +2n\pi \;, n\in \mathbb Z$$

and then

$$\cos (\omega fx_1)= \cos (\omega kx_1) \iff \omega fx_1=\omega kx_1+2n\pi \;\lor \; fx_1=-\omega kx_1 +2n\pi$$

Comment: WOW! Thank you :)

Comment: @Hulla You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @Hulla Refer also to the [figure here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2826229/505767).

Comment: Can you explain why we need the last term 2*n*pi where n>0?

Comment: @Hulla Because cos function is periodic with period $2\pi$. Therefore if $A=B$ is a solution also $A=B+2\pi$, $A=B+4\pi$,...,$A=B+2n\pi$ are solutions. Note that in general $n$ can be also negative.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\cos(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$
You will get $$-2\sin(\frac{wfx-wkx}{2})\sin(\frac{wfx+wkx}{2})=0$$
Not that $$\sin(x)=0$$ if $x=2k\pi$

Comment: But how do I solve for k like in the question?