# General solution of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

What is the significance of the general solution of trigonometric equations?

$\sin 5x+\sin x= \sin 4x+\sin 2x$ on simplification becomes $\cos 2x=\cos x$ which can be transformed to $\sin 2x=\sin x$.
The general solution of  both forms are different.

for $\cos 2x=\cos x$ , it is $2n\pi /3$ and for $\sin 2x=\sin x$, it is $(2n+1)\pi /3$.

Please tell me  the significance of general solution.

Comment: May I ask, how did you get from
$$
\sin 5x  + \sin x = \sin 4x  + \sin 2x
$$
to
$$
\cos 2x = \cos x
$$?

Comment: @MattiP. By observing $\sin 5x + \sin x = 2 \sin 3x \cos 2x$ etc. and simplify. This shows that one must also consider the solutions to $\sin 3x = 0$.

Comment: "$\cos2x=\cos x$ which can be transformed to $\sin2x=\sin x$": are you sure ? Please better explain what you are doing.

Comment: extremely sorry ! my mistake

Comment: Thank you @MattiP.So sin3x=0 generalizes the solution to npi/3?

Answer (score 1):

In general, by the definition on the unit circle and for symmetry we have that

$$\cos \theta = \cos \alpha \iff \theta=\alpha +2k\pi \quad \lor \quad \theta=-\alpha +2k\pi$$

therefore in this case

$$\cos 2x = \cos x \iff 2x=x +2k\pi \quad \lor \quad 2x=-x +2k\pi$$

which leads to the solutions

$$x= \frac23k\pi \quad \lor \quad x= 2k\pi$$

which corresponds to $x= \frac23k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb Z$.

Refer to the related

- [Solving $\cos(3x) = \cos(2x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2826222/505767)

---

As an alternative, in this case we can also use that

$$\cos 2x=\cos x \iff 2 \cos^2 x- \cos x -1=0$$

which leads to $\cos x=-\frac12$ and $\cos x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin 5x+\sin x=\sin 4x +\sin 2x$$

$$2\sin 3x\cos 2x=2\sin 3x \cos x$$

$$\cos 2x=\cos x$$

$$2x=2n\pi \pm x$$

$$x=\frac{2n\pi}{3},2n\pi$$

You would have also to consider the other case when

$$\sin 3x=0$$

$$3x=n\pi$$

$$x=\frac{n\pi}{3}$$

where $n \in Z$

$\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ are periodic functions. They regularly repeat after an interval.

This arose the need of general solution.